# Android: AdMob settings

Tags: android, admob

My Android App is nearly finished and I added AdMob as an advertising service.
Question: What are my final settings that I can submit the App to the Market Place? Sometimes the Ad does not display. I have created the Publisher ID that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

But sometimes your ad *does* display? 
Then there's nothing you can do, sometimes there just aren't any ads to be shown.
What might improve your fill rate, is to enable Google Adsense in your app settings in your admob account.